# how to change the position of a view in runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have the following xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/MainBottomBarLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false" >


   <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/friendsbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone" >



            <include
                android:id="@+id/tooltipFriends"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/friendsonlineLayout"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
                layout="@layout/tooltip_friends"
                android:visibility="gone" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/friendsbar_layout_ls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone" >



            <include
                android:id="@+id/tooltipFriends_ls"
                android:layout_width="290dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/friendsonlineLayout"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
                layout="@layout/tooltip_friends"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to remove  `tooltipFriends_ls` view and replace it with `tooltipFriends` which will change its position on orientation change :

`tooltipFriends` will be in its current position when screen orientation is portrait

`tooltipFriends` will be in `tooltipFriends_ls` position when screen orientation is landscape

how can I move inner view to be sibling of another view?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach, create an extra folder for layouts called `layout-land` which will then look for a layout with the specified name (for example in the `setContentView` call) in the folder that matches the orientation.

This way you can have two different layouts for the same activity, depending on orientation. Keep in mind that you'll have to save the state of views to keep user input such as text, upon orientation change.

Update:
If you still want to move the view, have two containers at the right places, say `R.id.container` and `R.id.container2` and when you  want to move the view from one to another you could do something like this:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.viewtobemoved); //The view
ViewGroup container2 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container2); //The new container
((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);  //Remove from current parent
container2.addView(view) //Insert in the new container
```

Comment: I cannot do this at the moment. only change position